# How to map a dictionary in Swift5?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I need some help :

```
if let dogFriends = dictionary[Key.dogFriends] as? [String: Int] {
            var newDogFriends = [String: FriendType]()

            dogFriends.forEach {
                newDogFriends[$0.key] = FriendType(rawValue: $0.value)
            }
        }
```

And I try to change a part of my code:

```
        dogFriends.forEach {
            newDogFriends[$0.key] = FriendType(rawValue: $0.value)
        }
```

Into this code(because swiftlint shows me a warning, I try to shorten my code):

```
 self.dogFriends = dogFriends.map{ ($0.key,: FriendType(rawValue: $0.value)) }
```

Throws the below error:

> Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'Property<[String : FriendType]>'

```
let dogFriend: [String: Int]

FriendType = enum FriendType : Int
```

Any help please?

Comment: `self.dogFriends` is an array of dictionaires based on that error, but your map returns an array of strings giving you two incompatible types.

Comment: so is there a way to map this code?

Comment: Yes, but it would help to give more context on what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to an create array of strings for all the dog names in `dogFriends`?  Also, why are you trying to set the value back to `dogFriends`, why not create a new `var` to hold the list of names?

Comment: I have a working foreach code:             dogFriends.forEach {
                newDogFriends[$0.key] = FriendType(rawValue: $0.value)
            }, but in this function I have a swiftlint warning : Cyclomatic Complexity Violation: Function should have . complexity 10 or less. So I am trying to shortcut my code to avoid the warning. @clawesome I have edited my first post so It shows more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map. In this line

```
self.dogFriends = dogFriends.map{ ($0.key,: FriendType(rawValue: $0.value)) }
```

Change

```
self.dogFriends =
```

To

```
let newDogFriends =
```

You cannot overwrite dogFriends with a different type.